# Django internationalization and localization performance difference?

Tags: django, performance, internationalization, translation

Regarding setting Django's `USE_I18N = False` in settings.py the documentation say:

> A boolean that specifies whether
>   Django's internationalization system
>   should be enabled. This provides an
>   easy way to turn it off, for
>   performance.

and:

> If you don’t use internationalization,
>   you should take the two seconds to set
>   USE_I18N = False in your settings
>   file.

This makes it sound like a big deal. Can anybody give me some information on how much performance I'm *really* gaining by turning it off until I need it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not a big deal. The only real change affects the *gettext family of functions available in the django.utils.translation package. If you set USE_I18N=False then Django will replace these functions with a faster implementation that doesn't actually try to translate the text. If you're not using any of the Django translation utils then it shouldn't matter one way or the other. Even if you are using these functions, they're fast enough that any performance gains will be imperceptible.

Comment: That seems in line with what I've been seeing in my testing. Memory usage didn't decrease at all and queries were no quicker... Funny that the docs make such a strong case for it.

Comment: Submit a patch to tone them down.

Answer (score 0):

Using `USE_I18N = True` will likely create many duplicate rows in your cache if you use the `cache_page` decorator since the cache key gets the language code appended to it.

So if your site is used in many countries this will have a massive impact on your cache hits and cache memory requirements, which will likely have a significant impact on the performance and cost of your site.